# How to delete a part of the entry in ONE column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MySQL base table, and need to change stuffs in ONE column.

Entries in that column are:

```
Cat - Grey - small 
Cat - Grey - middle 
Dog - Grey - big 
Elephant - Grey - big
```

I need to delete middle word, so I can get Cat - small, Cat - middle..

So it's one column.

Comment: Use regex to extract the first and last word, set/update your field with the result

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace):

```
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE('- Grey -', '-', column);
```

Comment: UPDATE `table` SET `column` = REPLACE(`- Grey -`, '');

This worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic way to get the string without the middle word:

```
select concat(
  substring(oldcol,1,locate('-', oldcol)),
  substring(oldcol,length(oldcol) - locate("-", reverse(oldcol))+2)
) as newcol
from mytable
```